# PHP detect the first loop of the new day

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

My solutions works mostly but not really always :) What is the reliable/best solution?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$seconds_today = time() - strtotime('today');

while (true) {
    if ($seconds_today > time() - strtotime('today')) {
        print('First loop of the new day');
    }
    $seconds_today = time() - strtotime('today');
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you expect from this code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean by "detect the first loop of the new day"

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement so that we could have a clear picture.

Comment: this is just a sample - my real code is much too long to post it here. anyways i need to detect the first loop of the new day to trigger some actions once a day as soon as possible after midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of PHP syntaxe, but here is the idea :

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$previous_day = 0;

while (true) {
    if ($previous_day != strtotime('today')) {
        print('First loop of the new day');
        $previous_day = strtotime('today');
    }
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Comment: @xs0 hahaha - you both are fully right - i was just too dumb to be aware that i do not need the seconds but just the new day - what my question already implied ... thank you both for your fast and friendly advice!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to bother with seconds/time, if all you're interested is the day. In addition, if you check the time twice per loop, there's a chance you miss the switch, so it's more robust to check it exactly once.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$lastDay = date("Y-m-d");

while (true) {
    $now = date("Y-m-d");
    if ($now !== $lastDay) {
        $lastDay = $now;
        print("First loop of the new day");
    }
    sleep(1);
}

?>
```

Having said that, I'd use something like cron, if possible..

Comment: @DSB hahaha - you both are fully right - i was just too dumb to be aware that i do not need the seconds but just the new day - what my question already implied ... thank you both for your fast and friendly advice!

Comment: and of course this what you explained here 'In addition, if you check the time twice per loop, there's a chance you miss the switch, so it's more robust to check it exactly once' was the main problem with my solution beside that it overcomplicated things with using the seconds of the day. so again - thank you very much :)